# PowerPoint embedded font not visible by API

Tags: fonts, powerpoint

I wrote the code below to check if a PowerPoint presentation has some fonts embedded:

```
private void Application_PresentationSave(Presentation Pres)
    {
            foreach (Font font in Pres.Fonts)
                if (font.Embedded != Office.MsoTriState.msoTrue)
                {
                    UI.MessageBox.Show("Please embed the full font in the presentation."));
                    break;
                }
    }
```

According to Microsoft docs for PowerPoint 2010 [Font Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.powerpoint.font.embedded(v=office.14).aspx) the `.Embedded` property should be `MsoTriState.msoTrue` when the presentation actually embeds the font.

Unfortunately even saving the presentation by allowing font embedding (File / Options / Save / Embed Fonts) the **code never sees the font embedded**.

Comment: Perhaps the font's not embedded.  Not all fonts are embeddable, and PPT doesn't always tell you about it if you save a font that can't be embedded. Right-click the font file in Windows explorer and check the properties page to see if the font is embeddable.

Comment: Hi Steve, your are right the "font.Embeddable" returns "-1" (so probably false)... This from the code side.  But actually the font IS embedded because I can open the presentation in a PC that doesn't have that font installed and I see the right font in the slides. Bit strange...

Comment: Actually, -1 would indicate True, that the font is embeddable, but if the font's not been embedded, PPT/Windows will have substituted another font; if so, I'm not sure whether it'd be telling you about THAT font's embeddability instead.  Check the font.Embedded property instead and maybe create a simple one-slide version of the presentation with nothing but a bit of text and unzip the file to see if there's anything that looks like an embedded font hiding in the zip file.